# Finding depth at node points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

I am using arcmap 10.2 . I need to find out the depth at the node points of my "point" shapefile. For this, i have tried using extract multivalues from points(Spatial Analyst).I had a .csv Events file as input point feature and bathymetry file as raster feature but it fails with an error message:

> output point feature "empty"

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide the entire error message you are getting?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your ArcMap version, the full error message, and the inputs you used with Extract multi values.

Comment: Do the points and the raster share the same spatial reference system?  Most vector/raster operations require that those data share the same spatial reference system.

Comment: I have edited the question as was required. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multivalue to point tool adds a field to the existing point data set. Since this is an event layer it can't do that. You can either export your points to a standalone layer and run the tool on that or use the value to point tool 
(runs on a single raster and creates an exported point file), but I find that tool is flakey. Stick with the multivalue tool and use it on a shapefile.